# Angular Dialog: Close Self

Tags: angular, dialog

I have a component opening a dialog using this code:

```
// my.component.ts
const editorRef = this.editor.open(MyDialogComponent, {});
```

I understand I can close it using this code:

```
// my.component.ts
editorRef.close();
```

But how do I close it from within `MyDialogComponent` iself?

Tried this but didn't work:

```
// my-dialog.component.ts
this.close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using any library for dialog?

Comment: Create the stackblitz demo to get the quick help.